# Is this normal for machine learning model trained using Tensorflow Object Detection API

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, object-detection-api

TensorBoard[image]

I am new to machine learning. I am trying to train a hand detection model using Tensorflow Object Detection API. I am using [Ego hands](http://vision.soic.indiana.edu/projects/egohands/) Dataset. There are 4400 images in train and 400 in test.
I am using Tensorflow 1.15. I am pretty much following sentdex tutorial with some changes.
I am using ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco from model zoo.

The loss is between 1-2 after 5000 steps. Now its nearly 20000 steps and loss is still between 1-2. Is it normal or not? and should I train more?

Here's my config file if you want to take a look at it.

```
# SSD with Mobilenet v2 configuration for MSCOCO Dataset.
# Users should configure the fine_tune_checkpoint field in the train config as
# well as the label_map_path and input_path fields in the train_input_reader and
# eval_input_reader. Search for "PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED" to find the fields that
# should be configured.

model {
  ssd {
    num_classes: 1
    box_coder {
      faster_rcnn_box_coder {
        y_scale: 10.0
        x_scale: 10.0
        height_scale: 5.0
        width_scale: 5.0
      }
    }
    matcher {
      argmax_matcher {
        matched_threshold: 0.5
        unmatched_threshold: 0.5
        ignore_thresholds: false
        negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
        force_match_for_each_row: true
      }
    }
    similarity_calculator {
      iou_similarity {
      }
    }
    anchor_generator {
      ssd_anchor_generator {
        num_layers: 6
        min_scale: 0.2
        max_scale: 0.95
        aspect_ratios: 1.0
        aspect_ratios: 2.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.5
        aspect_ratios: 3.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.3333
      }
    }
    image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        height: 300
        width: 300
      }
    }
    box_predictor {
      convolutional_box_predictor {
        min_depth: 0
        max_depth: 0
        num_layers_before_predictor: 0
        use_dropout: false
        dropout_keep_probability: 0.8
        kernel_size: 1
        box_code_size: 4
        apply_sigmoid_to_scores: false
        conv_hyperparams {
          activation: RELU_6,
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.00004
            }
          }
          initializer {
            truncated_normal_initializer {
              stddev: 0.03
              mean: 0.0
            }
          }
          batch_norm {
            train: true,
            scale: true,
            center: true,
            decay: 0.9997,
            epsilon: 0.001,
          }
        }
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: 'ssd_mobilenet_v2'
      min_depth: 16
      depth_multiplier: 1.0
      conv_hyperparams {
        activation: RELU_6,
        regularizer {
          l2_regularizer {
            weight: 0.00004
          }
        }
        initializer {
          truncated_normal_initializer {
            stddev: 0.03
            mean: 0.0
          }
        }
        batch_norm {
          train: true,
          scale: true,
          center: true,
          decay: 0.9997,
          epsilon: 0.001,
        }
      }
    }
    loss {
      classification_loss {
        weighted_sigmoid {
        }
      }
      localization_loss {
        weighted_smooth_l1 {
        }
      }
      hard_example_miner {
        num_hard_examples: 3000
        iou_threshold: 0.99
        loss_type: CLASSIFICATION
        max_negatives_per_positive: 3
        min_negatives_per_image: 3
      }
      classification_weight: 1.0
      localization_weight: 1.0
    }
    normalize_loss_by_num_matches: true
    post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 1e-8
        iou_threshold: 0.6
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 100
      }
      score_converter: SIGMOID
    }
  }
}

train_config: {
  batch_size: 24
  optimizer {
    rms_prop_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        exponential_decay_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.004
          decay_steps: 800720
          decay_factor: 0.95
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
      decay: 0.9
      epsilon: 1.0
    }
  }
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29/model.ckpt"
  fine_tune_checkpoint_type: 'detection'
  # Note: The below line limits the training process to 200K steps, which we
  # empirically found to be sufficient enough to train the pets dataset. This
  # effectively bypasses the learning rate schedule (the learning rate will
  # never decay). Remove the below line to train indefinitely.
  num_steps: 200000
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    ssd_random_crop {
    }
  }
}

train_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
     input_path: "data/train-ego.record"
  }
 label_map_path: "data/hands_label_map.pbtxt"
}

eval_config: {
  num_examples: 8000
  # Note: The below line limits the evaluation process to 10 evaluations.
  # Remove the below line to evaluate indefinitely.
  max_evals: 10
}

eval_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "data/test-ego.record"
  }
   label_map_path: "data/hands_label_map.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_readers: 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite normal to see a big decrease in the loss value for the first epochs of a learning algorithm. This is because of the way how the backpropagation works.

You basically move in the direction of a gradient (the derivative of your loss function) by a more or less fixed size (learning rate), depending on how you are optimizing your model (Stochastic Gradient Descent, RMSprop, Adam, etc).

But if your model has reached convergence, it means that your optimizing algorithm is "stuck" in a local minimum of your loss function. E.g. it is unable to explore further because the larning rate is too small to "exit" the area.

If you are satisfied with the result, you could decide to stop the learning, (in keras there is a callback for early stopping, if your model is not improving)

If you are not, there are a lot of different possibile solutions, that involve the tuning of *hyperparameters*:

- change the optimizing algorithm and the learning rate
- change the network architecture, and therefore the loss function landscape
- do feature selection, feature engineering etc
- regularization if you are overfitting
- dropout if you are overfitting
- etc

Anyway it depends on your problem. There are thousand of factors to be taken into account